# Skipped a particular test method in testNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

i have a method and i want to run this method and then showing skip in report

```
@Test(priority = 18, dataProvider="excelSheetNameAsMethodName",dataProviderClass=ExcelDataProvider.class)
public void addNotesFromRequisitionListAndDetailsPage(String username,String emailID,String password) throws Exception {

    cbatLoginPage().enterEmailID(emailID, password);
    cbatMyAccountPage().verifyApplicantTrackingTile();
    cbatMyAccountPage().selectTile("Applicant Tracking");
    cbatHomePage().switchWindow();
    cbatHomePage().verifyCBATHomePage(username);
    cbatHomePage().selectWidget("MY REQUISITIONS");
    cbatRequisitionPage().clickFirstNoteIcon();
    String noteText = "Test Note "+ RandomGenerator.GenerateRandomNumber(3);
    cbatRequisitionPage().enterNewNote(noteText);
    cbatRequisitionPage().clickFirstNoteIcon();
    cbatRequisitionPage().verifyNoteAdded(noteText);
    cbatRequisitionPage().selectRequisition();
    cbatRequisitionPage().clickFilledNoteIcon();
    noteText = "Test Note "+ RandomGenerator.GenerateRandomNumber(3);
    cbatRequisitionPage().enterNewNote(noteText);
    cbatRequisitionPage().clickFilledNoteIcon();;
    cbatRequisitionPage().verifyNoteAdded(noteText);
}
```

how can i Skipped this test case ?
i use throw new skipexception("message") but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi ankush, I can't understand your problem. Are you want to ignore this test case or skipped specified condition? Did you examine [Skip Excepiton Test in TestNG](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng)? If it doesn't solve your problem, you should debug your test case. Maybe the code logic you wrote is preventing the test from being skipped.

Comment: hi, i want to skipped this test case

Comment: Did you try `@Test(enabled=false)`? It skips the specified test case.

Comment: this method is use to ignore the test. I want to show my report that this test case is skip

Comment: I found a solution [to Capture Skipped Automation Tests in Extent Report](https://blog.kiprosh.com/how-to-add-skipped-test-functions-to-the-extent-report/). Maybe this can help you.

Comment: @ankushsingh You haven't mentioned how you tried `skipexception`. Because this exception is used to mark a test as skipped and it should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider you have method A and method B . add annotation depends on tag in your method B so if method A fails method B will be skipped.

```
@Test(priority = 1, dependsOnMethods = "administration_device_configure_custom_fields_default")
```

Comment: this test method does not depend on any of the methods.